# How do I convert my Ubuntu installation into a Live-USB or Live-CD?

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, remastersys

Say I have Ubuntu installed in a hard drive

What can I do to generate a liveUSB that is as similar as possible to the installation ?

Comment: (similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/158784/make-a-live-usb-of-your-installed-ubuntu , but there, he wants a kiosk instalation of ubuntu, and accepts other alternatives that dont involve liveUSB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [Remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/index.html).

This will create a hardware-independent LiveCD ISO backup of your system; you can then use a tool such as [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sf.net) to "burn" the ISO to a USB and create a LiveUSB.

Remastersys includes both command-line and GUI front-ends. Note that the author recommends starting with a "clean" install and then customizing it to maintain the highest compatibility for the LiveCD/LiveUSB. There is also a 4GB final size limitation, which means that your Ubuntu install should be around 8GB at most, and you should not include any media files, deb files, etc.

Comment: I havent tryed it yet, but it looks promissing

Comment: It looks like that remastersys tool is discontinued

Comment: There is a fork of Remastersys that is still under active development, available here: http://system-imaging.blogspot.co.nz/