# How do I use dd to clone an external USB drive installation to a local hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, dd

can I use the `dd` command to clone my ubuntu installation from my external disk to my local hard drive. will it even boot? I think I can, but not sure. do I need to make the output partition on my local disk the exact size as the input partition on the usb? I'm thinking install and boot off a liveusb on a different small flash drive and run something like `sudo dd if=/media/usbexternaldisk of=/media/localdisk` would that work as is?

also if I make an iso image of my external ubuntu installation using `dd`, can I burn it onto disk or unto another hard drive and have that boot up?

Comment: You can consider [my answer on SU](https://superuser.com/q/1050894/910769). Two other notable ressources:  http://tecmint.com/clone-linux-partitions and http://cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-dd-create-make-disk-image-commands

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Using *dd* to clone an Ubuntu installation

Yes, you can use *dd* to clone an installation, but it's not the fastest/easiest way to do it. It's better to do it via backup/restore with a live-tool such as [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

- If you wish to use *dd*, note that the target disk **must be the same size or larger** than the source.
- Also, to make it bootable, you **must copy from device-to-device** (e.g. `/dev/sdX`), NOT from partition to partition (`/media/...`)
- Use `sudo fdisk -l` or `gparted` to find out which block devices your target internal hard disk (usually `/dev/sda`) and external USB hard disk (usually `/dev/sdb`) are.
- Then use `dd` with **exactly** the following syntax, where `x` is the letter for the USB drive and y the letter for the internal drive which you have determined in the previous step:

  ```
    sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy bs=8M && sync
  ```

  and wait for it to complete.
- To answer your other question, no, simply *dd'ing* to an ISO (or CD or DVD, etc.) will NOT work; it will be unbootable. For that, you need to use a tool such as *remastersys*. See this question for more information:

  > [How do I convert my Ubuntu installation into a Live-USB or Live-CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158865/how-do-i-convert-my-ubuntu-installation-into-a-live-usb)

Comment: [Other tools like `cat` could actually be faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9492)