# move/clone existing external USB installation to internal partition shared with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, cloning

My question is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186131/how-do-i-use-dd-to-clone-an-external-usb-drive-installation-to-a-local-hard-disk), except I'm trying to clone my existing Ubuntu installation on a 40GiB external drive to a new partition on an internal drive shared with Windows.  I've been running from the external drive for a while and have already setup another user and installed software on the external drive installation.  I would now like to move this installation to my internal hard drive.  I reran the Ubuntu installer on the internal drive and already have the new ext4 partition with fresh Ubuntu install (maybe an unnecessary step).  Now I want the external drive installation copied to that internal drive partition.

My understanding is that, if I want the clone to be bootable, dd can only be used to copy from device to device and not partition to partition, or what I believe I need to do in my case would be device (external USB drive) to partition (ext4 partition on internal drive).  Looking at the Clonezilla documentation, it appears to have a similar limitation.  So maybe cloning is not what I need to do.  I really just want to get the additional user and all updates, changes, and installations copied over to the internal drive installation, so what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I still think clonezilla is the way to go it has option to copy and restore partitions usb/internal dosent matter as long as ubuntu was running just format the partition where you wanna install ubuntu same as where it is installed .Or you can make a custom distro with all your apps and files. There used to be an awesome tool for this called remastersys but they terminated the support after ubuntu 12 *boooo* .anyways there are similar tools like remastersys you can look into it.

Comment: Thanks, Clonezilla was the way to go.  After creating and running the boot disc, there are options to clone entire disc or just partition.  It turns out the partition I wanted to copy to was smaller than the source partition, which it doesn't allow.  If you run Clonezilla in advanced or expert mode, there is an option to "Try to resize the filesystem to fit the partition size" (-r) to fit on the smaller destination partition.  Got everything cloned and up and running.  Thanks for the tip.