# Cloning external HDD to internal HDD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

The process of cloning an internal hard drive onto an external one is pretty well described by online guides, but I can't seem to find any info on the opposite.

I want to replace my internal SSD with another one (I'm on a laptop, so I can't just plugin both SSDs at the same time). I've cloned its content to an external HDD and I would like to know if it's possible to copy the external HDD to the one installed.

I have thought of installing Ubuntu on the new SSD, but I'm not sure if I can copy the partitions of the external HDD to the internal while the PC is booted from the internal.

Would booting from an Ubuntu USB stick and doing the cloning from there work?  Can I use the `dd` command for an external HDD, too?
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I would boot Ubuntu on USB stick and clone the ssd when none of them are not mounted as root. I think that's the simplest way to do it without special software.

Comment: As long as the destination drive is larger than the source drive, you can use `clonezilla` to clone them, and then `gparted` to adjust partitions. You'll have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and install `clonezilla`, or create a `Clonezilla` DVD.

Comment: Please don't cross post your questions on different stackexchange sites.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097683/lubuntu-18-10-x64-installed-on-usb-stick-clone-to-usb-stick-2/1097733#1097733) can help you avoid some pitfalls. You can clone with `dd` (simple but risky and slow), or with Clonezilla (boot a USB pendrive or DVD disk made from a stable clonezilla.iso file; safer, faster). Good luck :-)

Comment: I believe in a new clean install. Then you can restore from your backups. That then is a good test your backups are complete. And if not everything to make system complete, you still have old drive to find missing data. When hard drive fails you will not have old drive to go back to, so need good verified backups. https://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders I also export list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall all of them. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: @Kev Inski I am glad that this question was posted on both sites. I would have never seen it, if it was only posted on the other site.