# Can I copy Ubuntu from my computer to a flash drive?

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive, usb-installation

I have Ubuntu on my computer already, but is it possible to copy the whole operating system to a flash drive? I wish to boot that OS, with all the files on it, on a separate computer.

Comment: Related: [How do I convert my Ubuntu installation into a Live-USB or Live-CD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/158865/367990)

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have to download Ubuntu to the flash drive, then add the files separately.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Visit the above link to download the 32 or 64 bit distro, then just use a separate USB stick for the files you want to add. Or install the distro, then use the same USB to transfer the files after the installation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

It might actually work just long enough, just well enough to sucker you in to spending hours trying to fix it before you give up and follow GFiasco's advise.

When you installed Ubuntu (or any OS on any computer), the installation process includes creating a boatload of configuration files based on the hardware the installer detects. Using that installation on other hardware *might* work poorly before it crashes if the two systems were pretty similar. Not likely, though.

Also, a flash drive would be pretty slow, unless you've got USB 3.0.